# Codeigniter load data from different folder model

Tags: codeigniter

```
$this->load->model('product/Product_model');
$product_data['p_data'] = $this->Product_model->fetch_data();
$this->load->model('catagory/Catagory_model');
$cdata['catagory_data'] =  $this->Catagory_model->getAllcategory();
```

I want to sent **$product_data['p_data']** and **$cdata['catagory_data']** in  $alldata['all']

```
$this->load->view('product/index',$alldata);
```

Comment: show the view code to know how you are calling the `$alldata` variable.

Comment: <?php
     foreach ($alldata as $product_info ) {
      
       echo $product_info->id ;
    }
   ?>
   <select name="catagory" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Catagory" required>
            <option>Select a category</option>
            <?php
      foreach ($alldata as $key ) {
          echo '<option value = "'.$key->id.'" >'.$key->catagory_name.'</option>';
      }
      ?>
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `alldata` something like below:

```
<?php
$this->load->model('product/Product_model');
$this->load->model('catagory/Catagory_model');
$alldata['p_data'] = $this->Product_model->fetch_data();
$alldata['catagory_data'] =  $this->Catagory_model->getAllcategory();;
$this->load->view('product/index',$alldata);
?>
```

Extract alldata in `index` view.

Comment: After apply your suggesion i got following error  **A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: alldata**

Comment: @Monzur where did you get this error? is it in view?

Comment: how are you trying to get the values? can you please post `view` code?

Comment: Here is the view code :   <?php
   foreach ($alldata as $product_info ) {
      
       echo $product_info->id ;
    }
   
   <select name="catagory" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Catagory" required>
            <option>Select a category</option>
            <?php
      foreach ($alldata as $key ) {
          echo '<option value = "'.$key->id.'" >'.$key->catagory_name.'</option>';
      }
      ?>
</select>

Comment: @Monzur you have to loop for `$p_data` and `$catagory_data` separately..